# Best way to utilize bash script (Ubuntu) Rscript, pdflatx, and API

Tags: r, api, bash, pdflatex, rscript

I'm currently writing some code that

1. connect to a server via API and fetches a bunch of data,
2. organizes that data by case ID,
3. generates an individual case report,
4. creates one pdf (case overview) file per case, and finally
5. pushes these files back to the server.

I'm quite familiar with R and somewhat familiar with pdflatex. I've just found out about bash scripts-as I have started to work in a Ubuntu environment-and I am now starting to realize that it is not straightforward which programs are best suited for the job.

My current plan is to fetch the data using RCrul in R, organize the data in R and generate a bunch of .tex-files. Hereafter I plan to use pdflatex to create teh pdf-files, and finally use R again to push the newly create pdf files back to the server. I’ve started writing a small bash script,

```
for f in *Rnw
do
# do something on ${f%%.*}
Rscript -e “source("fetch.data.and.generate.Rnw.R")”             # 1 through 3 
Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('${f%%.*}.Rnw')"                # 4
pdflatex "${f%%.*}.tex"                                          # 4 continued
rm "${f%%.*}.tex" "${f%%.*}.aux" "${f%%.*}.log" "${f%%.*}.out"   # cleanup after 4
Rscript -e “source("push.pdf.R")”                                # 5
done
```

I hoped someone out there could advise me about what software is best suited for the individual part of the job and what would give my the best performance.

The data is not that extensive, I will be working with about 500 to 2000 cases and approximately 20 to 30 variables.

Comment: If you are more familiar with R than bash scripting, why not write everything as one R script? From there, you can call pdflatex via a `system()` call.

Comment: agree with "use R", but think about it the other way, if you timed each aspect of your processing, the R calcs and the pdflatex conversion are likely to be 99% of the time and CPU. There's no obvious performance advantage (in run-time) to be had using a shell in this situation. Shell programming is more about developer efficiency than run-time efficiency (or certainly in this case). Shell programming offers the possibility that you can produce more end-user results in less time, which is a good thing, so as so many things in programming, "its a tradeoff". Just MHO. Good luck.

Comment: @flodel and @shellter, thanks for recommendation. I have actually never used `system()` before, but it sounds as a great solution in my case.

Comment: flodel or shellter, can one of you change your comment to an answer? I would like to mark this question as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@flodel and @shellter make excellent points.  I'll only add that, if you decide to keep using bash in your solution, you might find it easier to calculate your filename variable once and then use that elsewhere:

```
for f in *Rnw; do
    stem="${f%%.*}"
    Rscript commands with $stem
    pdflatex command involving $stem
    Rscript commands for pushing $stem.pdf
    rm $stem.*
end
```